# javascript how to stop loop four less than elems.length?

Tags: javascript, loops

This should be easy, but I'm apparently ridiculous with syntax if I have

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
```

but I want to stop 4 tags before the end. How do I write that? The below does not work or a variety of other variations.

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("details");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length -4; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
  }
```

Comment: This got NOTHING to do with ASP. Please tag properly in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You did it right, but you forgot to check if elems.length-4 is greater than 0. If it is not, your for-loop will never execute.

You probably want something like this:

```
var l = elems.length;
for (i = 0; i < (l > 4 ? l - 4 : l; i++) {
   elems[i].setAttribute("open", "true");
}
```

This loop will skip the last four elements, but only if there are more than four elements in total.

Comment: By the way, your code (with its use of DOM) looks more like JavaScript for web browsers than like ASP. Where do you want this code to run?

Comment: There are 30 odd elements ... running my code without the check opens all the tags. Running your code opens nothing ... ? Very confused.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I executed a number of other methods that visually changed the page enough to make me think the code wasn't working. This snippet works fine ... now to fix the other stuff under it.

Comment: @Ulf this is indeed pure client side JavaScript, OP didn't bother to find the proper tag for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. please see this snippet

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("p");

function openAll() {
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length-4; i++){
    elems[i].setAttribute("class", "open");
  }
  
  }
  openAll();
```

```css
.open{
  display:bolck
}

.close{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
<p class="close">hello</p>
```